# How to eliminate double-normals on selective faces?

Tags: modeling

As you can see in the object below, somehow I ended up with some faces having normals pointing in AND out, and other just pointing out. (I only want normals pointing out).

How can I get rid of the normals pointing in? I tried recalculating, (out and in), tried flipping normals, etc., removed doubles, checked and unchecked backface culling, applied scale and rotation, etc., but nothing has worked so far.

(A second question, is why do I have the double magenta lines? I tried to add edge creases, and next thing I knew, I had those double magenta lines and I can't get rid of them).

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: are you sure the faces with double normals are just one face?  Not trying to be annoying, but the most plausible idea would be that there are two faces on top of each other.  Please humor me.

Comment: Thank you @RBlong2us! It turns out you were right on that. I thought by removing doubles that I would have gotten rid of one face on top of the other, but apparently, somehow, the two faces were on top of each other just enough to mess with the shading, but not enough to share vertices.

Comment: Last question . . . Any ideas about the magenta lines?

Comment: I am pretty sure that's crease settings.  If you have mesh selected, you will find it in the tool bar which pulls up when you press "N", under Transform.  If you turn the Mean Crease down to zero, it will go away.  Glad to be of service :)

Comment: Mean Crease is used to sharpen an edge when using the subdivision surface modifier.  The stronger the Mean Crease, the less effect the subsurf modifier has on it.

Comment: Many thanks. I turned Mean Crease to Zero, but unfortunately, still have the Magenta lines . . .

Comment: ok, i'll look into it

Comment: Did you do anything in particular to the mesh?  Know when they first became that color?

Comment: My only recollection was that it happened after adding Edge Crease and/or subsurf modifier. But I think it was related to Edge Crease . . .

Comment: did you select all of the edges before you set Mean Crease to 0 ? it should remove the crease though if you select all of them first